# What do you call someone who is a member of the Orthodox Church?

Tags: word-choice

The people who are connected to the Catholic Church are called Catholics. The ones who are connected to the Protestant Church are called Protestants.

What about the people who are connected to the Orthodox Church? What do you call them in English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're called *Orthodox Christians*.

From the horse's mouth:

> What Orthodox Christians Believe

[Antiochian Orthodox Christian Archdiocese of North America](http://ww1.antiochian.org/whatorthodoxbelieve)

> Are Orthodox Christians “Bible believing?”

[Orthodox Church in America](https://www.oca.org/questions/otherconfessions/are-orthodox-christians-bible-believing)

And from a secular group that studies religious groups:

> Concentrated in Europe, Orthodox Christians have declined as a percentage of the global population, but Ethiopian community is highly observant and growing

[Pew Research Center](https://www.pewforum.org/2017/11/08/orthodox-christianity-in-the-21st-century/)

Comment: You will also hear people use the regional affiliation. For example, "He is Russian Orthodox," or "She is Bulgarian Orthodox."  Saying "He is Orthodox" doesn't really work because small-o "orthodox" is a more generic term in English (and it applies to Jews as well as Christians), but sometimes people will say, "He is [Eastern Orthodox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Orthodox_Church)," since the regions adhering to the Orthodox Church are generally east of the regions adhering to the Catholic Church.